# How do I search thru a class for an object and print one of the object's properties?

Tags: java, class, object

My class

```
public class Dog {
    public String name, breed;

    public Dog(String name, String breed){
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getBreed(){
        return breed;
    }
}

Dog newDog = ("Snoopy","Beagle");
Dog newDog = ("Cerberus","Hell hound");
```

I wanna make a method where I search class `Dog` with the String "Snoopy" and get back "Beagle".

I'm new to Java and Object Oriented Programming.

How do I accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can't - it doesn't work that way. There is no "list of all objects".

Comment: What is there, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd most probably want all your Objects of type `Dog` to be stored in some form of an array, say `ArrayList`. You would then iterate through like so:

```
for (Dog d : dogs){
   if (d.getName().equals("Snoopy")
      System.out.println("Dog's breed: " + d.getBreed());
}
```

That is the only quick way that I can currently think of. Hope this helps.

Do note that there is no, *global* list of all objects. You won't be able to search through any objects unless those objects are stored in a list of some sort.

Comment: So I would need something like `public ArrayList<Dog> dogObjList;`?

Comment: Yes indeed, you would need to instantiate an array like so -- `ArrayList<Dog> dogs= new ArrayList<Dog>()` - which would would then allow you to perform a for-each as I've specified in the answer.